# Available drives list in Win 10 System Restore dialog

Tags: windows-10

Why is there a SYSTEM folder under the available drives list?  I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere, no matter how I configure my search phrase.

[image: System Properties dialog]

Comment: It might be the boot partition or WinRE. I would recommend you just ignore it.

Comment: @Candy, thanks for the reply, and yes, I have been ignoring it.  I couldn't see any obvious reason or it showing up here, but it shows up on some of my other computers too. I'm sure you're correct, thanks.

Comment: It could be the WinRE partition. If it's more than 1 GB, it shows up there. [Drive appears when in system properties - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_11-hardware/drive-appears-when-in-system-properties/1b9220c5-1a0b-483f-b14d-b9f50c32d70a?messageId=66553562-ac80-41b7-b29c-31d27694ae7e&page=10)